My Internal hard drive became write-protected, cannot download files, need to write-enable
From properties I changed the permissions. After rebooting succeeded in downloading files first few times, then again the same problem. For the same reason firefox cannot save bookmarks or save passwords. Here is the output of mount which shows the sda2 is ro.
root@fedora:/home/som# mount
/dev/sda2 on / type btrfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/root)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=4096k,nr_inodes=1003745,mode=755,inode64)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=1622896k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=6542)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda2 on /home type btrfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/home)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=811444k,nr_inodes=202861,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/som/Expansion Drive type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

I tried umount as follows
root@fedora:/home/som# umount /dev/sda2
umount: /home: target is busy.

Please find me a solution to make it rw

I don't use btrfs - but it sounds like a filesystem issue.  I'd suggest backing up, then rebooting to recovery and fsck'ing /dev/sda2

Actually, you may be able to do fsck without going to recovery - One reason you could not unmount /home was because you were in it.  before running umount /dev/sda2 try shifting to another directory, eg cd /tmp   - If that then lets you unmount the filesystem you should be able to fsck it.

(1) What is the output of sudo dmesg | grep sda2? (2) fsck.btrfs is a no-op (see man fsck.btrfs). There is btrfs check (see man btrfs-check), but first I would check the health of the device itself; so… (3) What is the output of sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda?
